# How to submit a form which is inside another form in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an Html form which has a submit button, and inside the form, i have multiple sections which needs to be submitted individually. Since Html doesnt support Nested forms, How can i go about it? And also each section needs to be validated before getting submitted.

```
<%  using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post))
        { %>
<form id="frmHomeContact" method="post"  >
                       -- a partial view is rendered here
                       <div class="grid-2-12">

                            <input style="width: 100%;" type="button" title="save" value="save" />
                        </div>
                      </form>

<%}%>
```

Let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#frmHomeContact').on('submit', function(){
    var $this = $(this); // catch a reference to the form
    $.ajax({
        url: '/', //this should probably be the path to your controller
        type: 'POST',
        data: $this.serialize(), //name=George&msg=hello..etc <--note $this not $(this)
        success: function(){
            console.log('Successful submission.');
        }
    });
    return false; //submitting the form will no longer cause the browser to refresh.
});
```

Comment: Should the button type be "submit"? I tried but its not working.

Comment: What version of jQuery do you have? this requires 1.7, use `$('#frmHomeContact').submit(` if you're using a version lower than 1.7

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Your html code look like this:

```
<%  using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post),new { id = "frmHomeContact" })
        { %>
<form  method="post"  >
                       -- a partial view is rendered here
                       <div class="grid-2-12">

                            <input style="width: 100%;" type="button" title="save" value="save" />
                        </div>
                      </form>
<%}%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#frmHomeContact").submit(function() {
    var $this = $(this); // catch a reference to the form
        $.ajax({
            url: '/', //this should probably be the path to your controller
            type: 'POST',
            data: $this.serialize(), //name=George&msg=hello..etc <--note $this not $(this)
            success: function(){
                alert('Successful submission.');
            }
        });
        return false; //submitting the form will no longer cause the browser to refresh.
    });
</script>
```

You can get value of individual text box by using `var txtname= $('#txtid').val();` and check whether txt name is empty or not.

Comment: I hope u r mistaken. 'frmHomeContact' is the id of the inner form.